# login process more than 1 user id

Tags: php, login-script

I just want to know how to add and set 2 different username and admin for the login process. I don't know how to write the code after the shown step.

```html
 <?php
include ("connection.php")
$username = $_GET ['username']
$password = $_GET ['password']

if (empty ($username)) || (empty ($password)))
{
die ("Fill the empty field");
}

else if (($username=="aqilah")) && (($password=="aqilah")) 
//how to add another different username and password here
```

Comment: What is `connection.php`? One assumes it accesses a database so why not use that functionality?

Comment: just do another `else if`

Comment: ... and sort out the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this :

```
<?php
include ("connection.php");

$users = array(
    'foo'   => 'bar',
    'bar'   => 'foobar',
    'merry' => 'xmas',
); 

if (empty($username) || empty ($password)) {
    die ("Fill the empty field");
}elseif(isset($users[$username]) && $users[$username] == $password) {
  // success
}
```

Comment: You need to sort out the brackets

Comment: Humf yes still enjoying my first cup of coffee sorted it out